# Margin notes with horizontal bar

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote

I would like to include following margin notes into my document:

[image]

How can I include such grey lines shown in this image above and below my notes?
Also, my margin notes are entirely cut off:

[image]

I am using document class book, and the following command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\parindent{0ex}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marginnote}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{test}{RGB}{138,0,43}


\titleformat{\section}
{\color{test}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{test}\thesection}{1em}{}


\title{Draft }
\author{test}
 \raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\maketitle



\chapter{Introduction}



\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}


Test test

\marginpar{{\color{brown}BOLD} This is a margin note 
using the geometry package, set at 
3cm vertical offset to the line it is typeseted.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: your image suggests that you have set `\marginparwidth` wider than the margin, but as you have shown no example code it is not possible to say where your code is wrong. please post a small but complete document that shows the problem

Comment: Ok will do!.........

Comment: @Pegah your code is not minimal. I doubt that e.g. `mathtools` is necessary to reproduce your issue. Also, if this is the preamble of your actual document, don't include `blindtext`. That package is just for dummy creation and I don't think you need dummy text in your work.

Comment: Also there is no need to load `graphics` if you load `graphicx`, same for `color` and `xcolor`.

Comment: And if you use the `caption` package, `capt-of` isn't necessary anymore, too. The `subfigure` package is superseded by the `subcaption` package. `hyperref` should be loaded last except for a few other packages which have to be loaded afterwards. `mathtools` does load `amsmath`, no need to load it a second time. You load `wrapfig` twice and I'm not sure whether you need `acro`, `glossaries` **and** `nomencl`. That's everything I spotted, but there might be more issues in your provided code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `\rule`s in your `\marginpar`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\marginrule{\textcolor{gray}{\rule{\marginparwidth}{.4pt}}}
\newcommand\mymarginpar[1]
  {%
    \marginpar{\marginrule\\#1\\[-0.5\baselineskip]\marginrule}%
  }

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1]
\mymarginpar{Ducks are awesome, but rabbits are better}%
\blindduck[2]

\end{document}
```

Alternative version using `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` of the `booktabs` package instead of custom rules:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\mymarginpar[1]
  {{%
    \arrayrulecolor{gray}%
    \marginpar{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\marginparwidth}@{}}\toprule
    #1\\\bottomrule\end{tabular}}%
  }}

\begin{document}
\blindduck[1]
\mymarginpar{Ducks are awesome, but rabbits are better}%
\blindduck[2]

\end{document}
```

Setup to include `geometry`:

```
\marginparwidth=4cm % change this to your liking
\usepackage
  [inner=3.5cm,outer=\dimexpr\marginparwidth+2\marginparsep\relax]
  {geometry}
```

It calculates the outer margin based on your `\marginparwidth`. Consider that a line width of more than about 80 characters (no fixed value here, depends on baseline skip and font size) makes a document considerably harder to read. (the above results in something around 88.6 characters per line).

Comment: works! which command helps my keeping the notes inside the page's border?

Comment: @Pegah I just didn't fiddle with the page layout in this code. I'll take a look at the code you provided in your question.

Comment: @Pegah the problem is caused by the way you load the `geometry` package. I'll work something out, give me a minute.

Comment: @Pegah if you are not forced to include `geometry` to match a page layout, consider not using it at all. The default page layout of the standard classes  are considered good typography and make a document easier to read (though it might seem like a waste of space to unexperienced typographers).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time & help!! This was btw also the reason I did not remove the extra packages from the "minimal example"...I thought that something not directly relevant might interfere...- when I remove geometry, the pages are extremly narrow (huge margin left and right), why is that?

Comment: @Pegah because the ideal line width on the default font size with the default baseline skip is that wide. If lines get too long our eyes have problems following them and skipping to the beginning of the next line, hence making stuff harder to read. Also for a two sided book the outer margin should be two times as wide as the inner (because the inner is doubled by the other page), giving a balanced look. The `geometry` package results in more than 115 characters per line with the settings you gave to it (`[left=3.5cm]`) which is notably more than the ideal average character count per line.